# Get triangle vertex fabricjs

Tags: javascript, fabricjs

I was wondering if there is a way built into fabric.js to grab a triangle's vertices or at least the lines of a triangle. My goal is to place circles at each vertex similar to the stickman example for lines [here](http://fabricjs.com/stickman/). Just like the demo code, if I can grab the lines for a triangle, I can use the lines' coordinates to place the circles.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After leaving this alone for a bit, I found the answer. For each shape, Fabric gives of the coordinates, labeled `oCoords`. All there is to do is look in the objects' properties (I'm using Chrome's debugging tools), find `oCoords` and use them for whatever you like.